# How can I add a column in a list where I can choose several items in the list then calculate the difference between them?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

as an example: I want to choose the percentage of how complete is the task ( in percentage) of an employee who works in 3 projects then calculate the difference between them.
**(100% - (the total of the 3 percentage values in the three projects)**

Answer (score 0):

While there is a way to do this, it's not going to work quite as dynamically as you would probably like.

1. Modify the View where you would like this feature added
2. Expand the "Totals" group
3. For the Percentage Column, select the total you would like (I believe you will need to do the 100%-X portion as the consumer of the information)
4. Save the View
5. Now you will see the Sum of Percentages directly in the view. As you filter the list, this number will adjust to only include the items you are currently able to see.

Comment: thank you for your response, there is one issue. I want to select the items that I want to add a certain calculation.